# Accessing windows scheduled tasks in Java

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

Is it possible to access the Windows Scheduled Tasks in Java?  I essentially want to create a scheduled task from a command interface.

Comment: See the discussion [here][1].......


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898647/what-is-the-best-solution-to-perform-scheduled-tasks-in-java-whatever-the-os

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fire at commands from java to create a schedule task.have a look
[here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313565)

[and how to execute commands from java](http://www.linglom.com/2007/06/06/how-to-run-command-line-or-execute-external-application-from-java/)

Comment: but i would prefer to scheduled a task in java rather than putting it to native